# Child Class is Null on Postback after changing info on a C# Razor Page Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, binding

I have a model in C# called `MemberDetailsModel` and `CommentsInfo`

```
public class MemberDetailsModel {
    public string Name {get;set;} 
    [BindProperty]
    public CommentsInfo Info {get;set;}
    public MemberDetailsModel {
         Name= "";
         Info = new CommentsInfo();
    }

}

public class CommentsInfoModel {
    public string CommentsInfo {get;set;}
    public CommentsInfoModel () {
        CommmentsInfo = "";
    }
}
```

I have an `index.cshtml` razor page

```
<partial name="Shared/MemberDetails" model="MemberDetails" />
```

On `CommmentsInfoView.cshtml` I have

```
<partial name="Shared/CommentsInfoView" model="CommentsInfo" />
```

Going back to `index.cshtml.cs` I have this set this

```
[BindProperty]
public MemberDetailsModel MemberDetails {get;set;}
```

There is a form on the razor page that has a partial View for `MemberDetailsModel` and then that has a partial view for `CommentsInfoModel`.

```
 public async Task OnGetAsync() {
      MemberDetails = new MemberDetailsModel();
 }

 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(
     var name = MemberDetails.Name // works
     var comments = MemberDetails.Info.Comments // comes up with an error MemberDetails.Info is NULL

 }
```

Why is the value of MemberDetails.Info not retained on Postback yet MemberDetails.Name is returned, is there something I am missing on the binding of the partial classes ?

Comment: On CommmentsInfoView.cshtml you have `name="Shared/CommentsInfoView"` ? Besides,  If you added minimal reproducible example, it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.